# What is the best way to format a Google Drive search query for a name [first & last] from a Google Sheet running a script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

My google sheets script queries my google drive folders to return the file names for all documents that match a variable name [first last]. Here's the script:

```
var search20 = sh1.getRange("B2").getValue();

var searchFor = 'title contains "JR"' + 'and fullText contains "' + search20 + '"';
Logger.log (searchFor);

var names =[];
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor);
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  var name = file.getName();
  names.push(name);

  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(names[i]);
  }
}
```

My script works well.

My question: How can I format my search term so that my script finds all instances of the variable (e.g., the name I’m searching for) and also avoid false positives.

The script sometimes fails to find documents that I know contain the name I’m searching for.

On the other hand, the script sometimes returns false positives.

False positives occur when a document in Drive contains both the first and last names I’m searching for, but not in succession.

For example, I search for “John Smith” and the script returns a document that contains the names
John Adams
&
Adam Smith

Is there a solid search operator that might work? The script doesn’t allow additional quotation marks around the name.

I’ve tried John*Smith without success.

I’ve had success with John/Smith but am still missing some documents with that operator.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you reviewed the documents ion for `searchFiles`? It links to the supported syntax, which also includes several examples and the associated caveats.

Comment: You want to retrieve the documents with the content including ``John Smith`` by searching ``John Smith``. If my understanding for your quetion is correct, how about modifying to ``var searchFor = 'title contains "JR"' + 'and fullText contains \'"' + search20 + '"\'';``?

Comment: [The document of Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-parameters) says that ``[2] The contains operator matches on an exact alphanumeric phrase if it is surrounded by double quotes. For example, if the fullText of a doc contains the string "Hello there world", then the query fullText contains '"Hello there"' will return a result, but the query fullText contains '"Hello world"' will not. Furthermore, since the search is alphanumeric, if the fullText of a doc contains the string "Hello_world", then the query fullText contains '"Hello world"' will return a result.``

Comment: What does adding the "\" to the scripted search criteria do? Thank you for the helpful suggestions.